# Cross Subdomain Cookie Not Working As Expected On Sub-Subdomain

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I am using a system to log in to a site that uses a number of subdomains of a subdomain. I have a development and live version of this system, however I am experiencing strange behaviour.

So, the setup is I have the following:

**Development environment:**

- dev.mydomain.com
- sub1.dev.mydomain.com
- sub2.dev.mydomain.com

**Live environment:**

- live.mydomain.com
- sub1.live.mydomain.com
- sub2.live.mydomain.com

As part of the login process, I use the following line to set the cookie:

```
setcookie("LoggedIn", 1, 0,'/','.mydomain.com');
```

This all works fine and I can log in once and access everything, however I want to restrict it so that if I log in on the test system, then I am not logged in to the live system and vice versa.

I expected the solution to this to be:

```
setcookie("LoggedIn", 1, 0,'/','.test.mydomain.com');
```

and

```
setcookie("LoggedIn", 1, 0,'/','.live.mydomain.com');
```

dependent on the system.

However, using this method I am able to log in to test.mydomain.com and live.mydomain.com independently but I am unable to log in to the sub-subdomains (sub1.test.mydomain.com, sub2. etc).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the physical file locations for these domains as in /subdomains/sub/ and /subdomains/sub.sub/ or /subdomains/sub/sub/

Answer (score 0):

It might because of [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Please go through it.

Comment: But if that was the case, it would not work in the first instance

Answer (score 0):

i totally agree with your expectation the subdomain cookie should have priority over top domain but in most web frameworks you can't have duplicate cookie id, so even if you set the cookie domain as top and subdomain still both are valid, so i think the safest solution is you should try to change the cookie id for that specific domain usually i put it in the application configuration as variable